# Handling keyboard events on cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have a textbox and every time something is typed into it. I want to capture the key pressed and perform some action. For this I need to capture the keyboard event. Currently I am trying to override the `keyDown:` function but it wont work.

So how can I do it?

Comment: It always helps to characterize "won't work." Crashes? Nothing happens? Keys appear in box, but no keyDown messages? Code is helpful, too. And is this a NSTextField or a NSTextView? Do you really need the event itself, or just the character?

Answer (score 1):

Don't override keyDown.  Register for notifications when the text control text has changed.  The following will work for an NSTextField:

```
// Listen for change events on fields
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(valueChanged:)
                                             name:@"NSControlTextDidChangeNotication"
                                           object:textField ];
```

...

```
 (void) valueChanged:(NSNotification*)notification {
  // TODO  -- look at the stringValue of your TextField
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
- (void)controlTextDidChange:(NSNotification *)aNotification
```

This will be use full if you need to validate the data in your textField ....